# Как поисковые системы взаимодействуют с базами данных?

Tags: elasticsearch, sphinx, поисковые-системы, полнотекстовый-поиск, lucene

Заранее прошу прощения за незнание, просто особо не доводилось иметь дело с поисковыми системами. Я не имею представления как поисковые системы вроде Sphinx, Elasticsearch или Lucene взаимодействуют с базами данных. Какие протоколы они используют? Как происходит сам поиск: упорядоченно(поисковая система сначала ищет у себя, потом делает запрос к бд, после чего результаты сливаются) или асинхронно(поисковая система делает запрос к бд, пока бд работает, поисковая система сама проводит поиск). Пытался найти больше информации о том как все это работает под капотом, но не нашел. Подскажите где можно почитать про это или же дайте развернутый ответ. Если вопрос показался слишком абстрактным, объясните хотя бы как работают в этом плане Sphinx, Elasticsearch и Lucene.

Comment: Никак не взаимодействуют. Это вы взаимодействуете с базой и потом передаёте нужные данные в Sphinx/Elastic/Lucene

Comment: andreymal, а для чего нужны всякие плагины для баз данных вроде  pg-sphinx? В чем их роль?

Comment: Это стоит уточнять в документации этих самых плагинов, но в общем и целом они необязательны для использования (и лично я их тоже никогда не использовал, так что более внятный ответ не дам). Держу три сайта с поиском на Sphinx без всяких плагинов и радуюсь жизни :)

Comment: andreymal, я правильно понимаю, что последовательность работы такова: сначала ты обращаешься к бд с запросом, потом результаты запроса, отсылаешь к поисковой системе, и только потом получаешь конечный результат?

Comment: Сначала данные один раз читаются из базы и помещаются в поисковую систему, чтобы на построила поисковый индекс (система не запоминает данные, а только строит индекс). Затем, когда становится нужно выполнить поиск, выполняется обращение к поисковой системе с запросом, она смотрит свой индекс и выдаёт идентификаторы объектов, соответствующих запросу. Затем с этими идентификаторами можно отправить запрос к основной базе, чтобы получить полные данные о найденных объектах.

Comment: Из этой схемы могут быть исключения, например, Elasticsearch по желанию может полностью хранить все данные в себе, и необходимости в другой базе данных вообще не будет. А Sphinx можно настроить так, чтобы он сам периодически ходил в базу и забирал себе данные для построения индекса. Но это всё уже необязательно, и я подобные плюшки на своих сайтах не использую (ибо не возникало необходимости, описанная выше схема работает для меня достаточно хорошо)

Comment: andreymal, вот интересна стадия, когда Sphinx периодически ходит в бд за данными для построения индекса, как в таком случае Sphinx общается с бд, через JDBC, ODBC?

Comment: Согласно документации, Sphinx поддерживает MySQL, PostgreSQL и ODBC

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104656/discussion-between-cvxbcvbsd-fsddfgdfg-and-andreymal).